# How can I change my display name in a Channel?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams, display-names

Whilst joining a Channel, I was offered to choose a name. I was informed it would be reflected in my developer story, so I chose a name I would only choose in that circumstance. I also made a large typo because I hit enter by accident whilst deleting part of that name.

Since it turns out it *isn't* actually in my developer story(!) and it's actually just a separate private pseudonym used just for that channel *and* I have a big typo in there, I'd like to change my display name for that Channel. But I can't find out where to do that.

- It's not my regular display name, so it doesn't seem like it's reflected anywhere in my profile settings.
- There's a switch for Public vs my channel on my Profile and Activity pages, but the [Edit Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/current) page has no such switch and I'm just taken to my Public profile page to edit that, not my Channel profile page.
- Despite the suggestions it doesn't actually seem to appear anywhere in my developer story, so there's no setting in there I can find to change it either.

**Where should I be looking to change my display name for my account in a Channel?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We shipped a change today so that now you can update your Teams display name without updating any Stack Overflow public user settings. You can find a site switcher dropdown at the top of the [Edit Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/current) page.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

This is what I have tried when I joined the channel.

Go to Edit Profile and then scroll down to the field where it is asking for your Full Name.

[image]

Just fill it in and the real name will start reflecting in the Channel and Developer Story etc.

Comment: Thanks. This did it. The typoed display name I chose for this channel was present in that field, and changing that field updated my channel display name.

Comment: This won't change your developer story

Comment: @CalvT븃 `Updates to your Full name will be reflected within your Developer Story and/or all Stack Overflow Teams. Within Developer Story, your name is seen by employers and visitors to your public CV/Story. Within Stack Overflow for Teams, your name is seen by members of that team.`

Comment: @AJ Yeah... it says that, but the Full Name in my developer story remains unchanged. I'll open a bug report about that. (It not changing is a Feature to me, but the message should be updated.)

Comment: @doppelgreener My name was changed in my developer story, though.

Comment: @AJ well my "Full Name" reads "CalvT", yet my developer story has my little weird character on the end