# My public display name in a Channel shouldn't be tied to my Private Information Full Name

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams, privacy, display-names

I've found based on a previous support request I made ([How can I change my display name in a Channel?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364661/how-can-i-change-my-display-name-in-a-channel)), the display name I have in a channel depends on the “Full name” I choose in my profile settings. Which is to say, setting this...

> [image: "test name for a channel" set as my full name]

... means I show up in a Channel's user list like this:

> [image: "test name for a channel" shows as my display name in the channel user list]

## This shouldn't be the case.

I should be able to set my display name *for each channel specifically.* Not all channels are going to be places I will want to use the exact same display name. Further, one of my channels is not related to my real life identity at all, but instead to my Stack Exchange identity, so I want to use my Stack Exchange pseudonym and not my real life name there.

Plus, on principle, the section fully titled “**Private information (not shown publicly)**” should not be used to set information that is, you know, shown publicly in a channel. Previously the information in this field was **strictly between Stack Exchange and myself.** It wasn't supposed to be a public display name feature, and shouldn't be adapted for that purpose.

(The warning says this field also affects my developer story, but [name changes to this field don't affect my developer story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364663/the-warning-about-my-private-information-is-inaccurate-name-changes-dont-affec) so I'm not sure what's going on there. I can at least set my developer story name to something different, which is good.)

Accordingly for the time being I've set my private information's full name to just “doppelgreener” so that this is the only name that shows up in channels I'm in, where I don't want my full name displayed.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368334/joining-a-team-forces-my-stack-overflow-identity-to-match-my-real-name

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We shipped a change today that completely separates your Stack Overflow public profile from your Teams profiles.

1. We added a site switcher dropdown to the Edit Profile page so that users with Teams can customize their profile per team.  We do not sync any settings on this page between Stack Overflow public and Teams. Updating your Real Name on Stack Overflow public does not update your display name nor real name on your Teams.
   [image]
2. The "Finish creating your Team profile" page during Teams onboarding does not sync the avatar and full name to the Stack Overflow public profile.

Answer (score 25):

Yes please. I had to drop my surname from my Full Name field (and thus my CV) because I was invited to the "Stack Exchange Moderators" team. I would have done the same had I been invited to some FOSS group.

Comment: I would have bountied this question 500, but since I can't, I placed this as an answer to bump the question up instead ‍♂️

Comment: FWIW you can have a [different developer story name to your full name](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364661), not sure if developer story name = cv name though