# Add a "role" line in Teams usercards for members to note their position or job title

Tags: feature-request, design, stack-overflow-for-teams, users, user-card

It'd be really useful to be able to see the role of the people you're interacting with on a team... meaning their job title, in most cases, but on some Teams it could be used for other things. On the Stack Moderators Team, we could use it to note which sites we moderate.

While you may often know who you're interacting with, on teams over a certain size, it may be nice to have a reminder. This could be configurable by the Admins (enable/disable) so that Teams that don't want it don't have to use it.

If the expandable hover cards were active for every user on a Team (rather than basing them on Stack Overflow reputation) - which they should be, an alternate would be to put the info there. It wouldn't increase the size of the user info box that way but would make it really quick to see the info if you needed it by hovering over the info box instead of needing to click on their profile and hoping that they had some info about their position there.

Since some users are on multiple Teams that may not relate to each other at all, this should be editable on a per-Team basis.

As an example, I'm on two Teams; the Charcoal Team and the Stack Moderators Team. Right now, the only "roles" assigned are the Team Admins, denoted with a hexagon similar to moderator diamonds.

On Charcoal, I'd probably leave this field blank as I don't fill a specific role within the Charcoal structure, though some of the other members have specific access that would be useful to note. For Charcoal, it may even be beneficial for these roles to be created/assigned by an Admin, rather than self-awarded.

On Stack Mods, I'd want to use this space to say that I'm a moderator on two sites, Interpersonal Skills and Arts & Crafts. This information could be self-volunteered by the member with filling it out at all being an option rather than a requirement.

---

This is sort of asking for two related things...

- something users can set
- something that team admins can set

They'd probably be either-or with the option to use neither. The end goal is to make it so that it's easier to see what role someone has within a Team without viewing their profile. How that's achieved is up to the Design Team/Devs to figure out.

Comment: _Technically_, you do already have a role assigned on the Charcoal team... you're a Team Guide. Whatever they do.

Comment: Where are those set? Are they even visible to non-Admins?

Comment: This would be especially useful on Stack Mods since Teams default to using real names ([ref1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364664/my-public-display-name-in-a-channel-shouldnt-be-tied-to-my-private-information), [ref2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368334/joining-a-team-forces-my-stack-overflow-identity-to-match-my-real-name)) and we mostly don't know each other in real life. Avatars only help so much.

Comment: @Catija Nope. You show up as Team Guide in the admin user management list; other people don't. That's literally the only difference, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score -3):

Perhaps this could be implemented by showing the custom Team Awards (shown in the profile) on the Usercard, such as the one [Collin Choy](https://stackoverflowteams.com/c/staging-ground-testing/users/62) has, in the Staging Ground Testing team:

[image]

This is a useful adaption since awards are already used for this purpose:

> "Custom awards are a great way to further reward engagement and encourage adoption of Teams. Create custom awards for projects, team goals, company goals, releases, and more to help drive engagement.".

Source: [Stack Overflow help](https://stackoverflow.help/en/articles/4548760-custom-awards).

I looked through his activity, it doesn't note earning the award, nor how it was earned. It would be more useful if that award was  <kbd>isAdmin</kbd>.