# Profile setting options very confusing on Teams

Tags: discussion, support, profile-page, stack-overflow-for-teams

The profile settings and display names for Teams is pretty confusing.  When I first signed up for Teams it used my private information (my full name) only within Teams.  I rechecked Stack Overflow public and all was good, that one still had a display name.

But then I thought I would check the settings for my "team" to see what user name it is using.  I could not find the field, but I noticed the first tab profile has a drop down allowing me to select which profile I want to view:

[image: Profile example]

This was nice because I could flip between my SO Profile and my Teams profile.  What I then tried to do was edit my profile.  But when I click this tab this drop down does not show up.  So I am thinking the user interface (The user experience) would be a bit more clear were it to have this drop down in this tab as well. Then allow me to change stuff from here:

[image: SOmeta 368399 question example]

I don't know what I am editing on this page as the top line is orange telling me I am on Stack Overflow. I guess what I am asking is display name should be available in both Stack Overflow and teams - it's OK if you want to use the full name but it should be a separate field and may default to your full name.

Comment: I expected more than a computer-generated-green-box from you, JonH.

Comment: It looks like a (very boxy) free hand red circle to me, are you red-green color blind? ;)

Comment: Yeah I'd have an opinion on this, however they refuse to send me a singup email to my company email address so I have given up

Comment: @TheGeneral sorry about that. It's a known issue caused by company IT policies blocking our email. If you submit a ticket we can help you get it resolved: https://www.stackoverflow.help/support/tickets/new

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that the profile is confusing and needs a lot of work. Here’s some context about how we got here and what we’re going to do about it.

Over the years as Stack Overflow’s offering has grown the profile and the settings to control your profile data have been adapted to accommodate this. These changes have been incremental and made on an ad hoc basis. However we’ve never had the opportunity to step back and consider what the Stack Overflow profile should be given everything we’ve learned about our users and how they use it.

The net result is a bloated product with a large amount of design and technical debt. Specifically we have 3 profiles (public profile, Developer Story and now Team profiles) for 3 audiences that share a large amount of data. This makes it very hard to know who can see your profile data and how you can control it.

We didn’t add a drop down to the settings tab because the majority of settings don’t make sense to be specific to a Team. For example logins, job preferences and site preferences do not apply. However there is some profile data such as job title or profile image that would be nice to be specific per Team. We chose not to allow customisation per Team to prevent further duplication of profile data that would be hard for users to manage - as we’ve seen happen on Developer Story.

For Teams we needed the ability for users to be identifiable within a Team to their colleagues. Knowing who wrote an answer and their role in your organisation is important for you to be able to trust that answer. Given display names are not identifiable we decided to reuse the real name field that is used on Developer Story and shared with employers (if you choose both of these to happen). Your real name takes the place of the display name wherever it is viewed within a Team. Only you and other members of the Team can see your Team profile.

You can update this at the bottom of the Edit Profile page under Edit Profile & Settings:
[image]

Over the next couple of months, now that Teams has launched and we’re learning a lot about how users use the product, we’re going to start planning profile improvements. These will likely include:

- Making it easier for users to know who can see their profile data and how they can control this
- Removing duplication of data and consolidating the number of profiles
- Allow customisation of how you appear to your colleagues within a Team

If you have any feedback about possible changes please do post on here!

Comment: *Given display names are not identifiable we decided to reuse the real name field that is used on Developer Story and shared with employers (if you choose both of these to happen).* If that's not available - does it default to the display name?

Comment: @JonClements as part of joining a Team users are asked to provide their real name (it's mandatory).

Comment: *Given display names are not identifiable we decided to reuse the real name field that is used on Developer Story and shared with employers* except that both of the teams I use **aren't** work-related. They're both SE related and no one knows my real name. I don't use jobs or dev stories so it's easy for me to put in my username as my real name but that's not the case for many people. Even in a work environment, someone might use a middle name or nickname that doesn't align with the name they want on their resume.

Comment: @Catija I agree. How you appear on your CV should be different to how you appear to your colleagues. Your use case it noted. However 99% of Teams created so far are for work. Although we ask for real name, it's fine for you to enter anything you like :)

Comment: @Kit I don't recall being asked to "enter a name" for the team I setup or the Stack Moderators team... it just *did it*

Comment: You can... but, from what I understand based on the giant warning banner, changes to your real name on a Team also change how your name appears on dev story/jobs.

Comment: @JonClements if you had previously provided your real name you would have seen a screen similar to this when joining the Team https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZh4P.png

Comment: @Kit ahh... so if I was inclined to do so I could have clicked edit profile?

Comment: @JonClements that's right. At which point you would have been told about the name being shared with other Teams and your Developer Story (if you have one)

Comment: @Catija correct. The use case you're talking about is someone who wants to remain anonymous to their Team but identifiable to employers, is that correct? That's not something we support as we've built Teams for companies. If we expand Teams outside of this core use case, we will need to revisit that.

Comment: I'm talking about this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/364664/4548692 the nickname/middle name is still an issue even on work-related teams. My husband goes by "Andy" but uses "Andrew" on resumes.

Comment: @Catija Noted. As I said above I agree we need to allow users to customise how they are viewed in their Team.